# Apache Cordova Launch external (Windows) app

Tags: cordova, command-line, external, launch

Is it possible to launch an external program via Cordova app? I would need this on Windows and MacOSX platforms at least.

Comment: FYI: cordova doesn't support MacOS platform.It only supports iOS which is for ipads and iphones

Comment: @ Arpit Vasani: That is not true, cordova supports OS X and Windows, have a look at the docs:  http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/index.html